# Remove brackets from the result of regular expressions in pandas

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column in pandas that looks like this:

```
>>> df['Name'][0]
'BTC  Bitcoin'
```

I want to create a column using regex that searches for 3-5 capital letters followed by two spaces. Then I use .split() to leave us with just the symbol. This is the regex formula I used:

```
symbols = []

for i in df['Name']:
    symbols.append(re.search(r"[A-Z]{3,5}\s\s", i).group().split())

df['Symbol'] = symbols
```

This is my result:

```
>>> df['Symbol'][0]
['BTC']
```

How do I get this same result but without the brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get `['BTC']` is because your expression `re.search(r"[A-Z]{3,5}\s\s", i).group().split()` results in a `list` object, for your example, it is `['BTC']`, and then you append this to an empty list `symbols` you defined outside of your for loop.

Therefore, your `symbols` list contains something like `[['BTC'], ['ETH'], ['BLA']]`.

If you want to avoid this, just change your expression to be

```
symbols.append(re.search(r"[A-Z]{3,5}\s\s", i).group().split()[0])
```